# Why I get user and not users on users/index route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js, ember-data

I tried to make a simple emberapp with rails, that shows some users info from our system.

My route: /api/users returns this json:

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"username":"Evolutio","email":"mail@evolutio.tld"}]}
```

My emberadapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'https://api.domain.tld',
    namespace: 'api',
    headers: {
        //"API_KEY": "secret key",
    }
});
```

my users/model.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string')
});
```

my users/index/route.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        let users = this.store.findAll("users");
        return users;
    }
});
```

I visit this url: localhost:4200/users

When I delete the user/model.js I get this error:

```
WARNING: Encountered "users" in payload, but no model was found for model name "user" (resolved model name using frontend@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("users"))
```

and the data with the ember inspector:
[image]

my index template from users:

```
<ul>
{{#each model as |user|}}
    <li>
        {{#link-to 'users.show' user}}
            {{user.username}} {{user.roles}}
        {{/link-to}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

my scnd problem is, that I cant make any relation.
my api returns now this:

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"username":"Evolutio","email":"mail@evolutio.sh","roles":[{"id":5,"name":"admin","alias":"Administrator"}]}]}
```

my user/model.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),

  roles: DS.hasMany('role'),
});
```

and now I got this error:

```
Error while processing route: users.index Assertion Failed: Passing classes to store methods has been removed. Please pass a dasherized string instead of undefined
```

I solved it with this:
my user_serializer.rb:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :username, :email, :display_role
  #has_many :roles

  def display_role
    "#{object.roles[0].alias}"
  end
end
```

and my user/model.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  display_role: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did really well, one thing what you have to change is the file name of your model. If you prefer to use pod syntax move `users/model.js` to `user/model.js`, or you can save it `app/model/user.js`.

The model is always in singular. The file name is in singular.

Update `app/index/route.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll("user");   
    }
});
```

If you've just started to learn Ember.js I have a blog post where you can learn more about the conventions: [Ember.js tutorial](http://yoember.com)

Comment: maye you can look into my second problem. 
I used your app that you linked in your homepage as base. But I can't get any mistake.

Comment: So you already have a `app/model/role.js` with `name` and `alias` field, plus a `user: belongsTo('user')`?

Comment: I solved it myself with a little workaround. I edited it above at the end.

Comment: Brilliant. Great job! :)

Comment: Maybe you can look into this problem too? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372594/ember-has-many-and-belongsto-doesnt-work